# What is this R function trying todo?

Tags: r, tableau-api

I have a R function like this:

```
SCRIPT_STR("
  library('ggmap');
  geo <- geocode(.arg1, output = 'latlon');
  geo$latlon <- do.call(paste, c(geo[c('lat', 'lon')], sep = ','));
  geo$latlon
  ", ATTR([Full Address]))
```

Could some body explain me in plain english what is this function trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, but a quick google-search reveals that `SCRIPT_STR` is used to communicate data from R to Tableau, so I would guess that this is something along those lines.

Comment: Yes its function available in tableau,but I am not understanding the `arguments` passed to it and library used `ggmap`

Answer (score 2):

`geocode` is a function for geocoding a location using Google Maps (`geo <- geocode(.arg1, output = 'latlon')`), then, for all the locations you are creating a text string with the latitude and longitude separated by a ,-sign (`do.call(paste, c(geo[c('lat', 'lon')], sep = ','))`). There will be one such text string printed/returned from the code for each location in the input.